# How to find height of DataGrid header?

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I need to find out the height of a DataGrid so I can set it explicitly. I can find the height of all data rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getRowCount(); i++) {
    height += getRowElement(i).getOffsetHeight();
}
```

but how do I find the height of a header? I know its height if all headers fit in one line, but in some situations a header may take more than one line.

Comment: The approach seems strange. Shouldn't you be using a `CellTable` instead then?

Comment: This DataGrid has over two hundred lines of code, and I use it in many places. I do not want to create a separate widget just for this use case when I place it within a FlowPanel (i.e. I have to set its height explicitly).